# calender view for my pagesLibrary in Publishing sharepoint site where user need to redirect to the page when click on event

Tags: calendar

I created one calender view for my Pages Library in Publishing Sharepoint Site.  Whenever I create a page in the page library on that particular day it will display event like "default.aspx". And when user clicks on that it will redirect to pages properties form. But I want to redirect the user for the page instead. How to get worked this?  Any suggestion will be great.